# Why the header function is not working after CURL call?

Tags: php, url, curl, http-headers, uri

Following is the call to an URL using CURL :

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    error_reporting(-1);

    $link = $_GET['link'];
    $url  = "http://www.complexknot.com/user/verify/link_".$link."/";


    // create a new cURL resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set URL and other appropriate options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    // grab URL and pass it to the browser
    curl_exec($ch);

    // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

The variable `$url` contains one URL which I'm hitting using CURL.

The logic written in the file(present in a variable `$url`) is working absolutely fine.

After executing the code I want the control to be redirected to one URL. For it I've written following code :

```
header('Location: http://www.complexknot.com/login.php');
exit;
```

The following code is not working. The URL `http://www.complexknot.com/login.php` is not opening and a blank white page appears. This is the issue I'm facing.

If I don't use the CURL and hit the URL i.e. the URL contained in `$url` then it gets redirect to the URL `http://www.complexknot.com/login.php` that means header function works fine when I hit the URL in browser.

Why it's not working when I call it from CURL?

Please someone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because CURL is outputting the data. You must use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` in order to let CURL returning data instead of outputting it.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
error_reporting(0);

$link = $_GET['link'];
$url  = "http://www.complexknot.com/user/verify/link_$link/";

// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

header('Location: http://www.complexknot.com/login.php');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please tell me where should I add this line or better would you please post my complete code with new line added as an answer so that I could accept your answer?

Comment: Sorry, but still the problem persists.

Comment: Can you try it like this (see my edited answer again). if it doesn't work just view the source of the page to see what is printed..

Comment: First of all thanks once again for your help. Your trick worked for me but I can't do like this. I want to redirect the URL from the file which I'm calling using CURL and not from a file from which I'm giving CURL call. If CURL prohibits this then you can suggest me some other better solution rather than using CURL. Waiting for your reply.

Comment: use `$result = curl_exec($ch)); die($result)` to see what is that page returning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92271/discussion-between-phplover-and-matei-mihai).

Comment: I really can't do it right now because I'm @work :) I will try help you later on.. thanks for understanding

Comment: yes sure, Thank you so much for the help you provided till now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`<?php echo "<script>window.location.href = 'http://www.complexknot.com/login.php';</script>";die; ?>`